# How to conditionally create Text children in column, based on selected Dropdownbutton item?

Tags: flutter

I'm pretty new to flutter and Dart, started learning some two weeks ago. My first app I'm trying to build as a starters project is a simple dosage calculator tool for calculating the amount of anesthetics you have to add based on number and weight of mice.

So to my problem: I managed to create the most basics elements of the UI and created a dropdown menu for the anesthesia protocol that the user wants to use. Based on the chosen element I would like to display different text elements in a column, representing the different meds that the protocol is composed of. For example if the user chooses MMF it will display Medetomidine, Midazolam and Fentanyl.

I have looked everywhere for the conditional creation of widgets, and haven't found a solution that suits my problem yet. Maybe I'm just not searching good enough. Since I know some Python I would have imagined it should be pretty simple to set something like this up using if statements based on a variable that gets created when the selectedItem is changed. However I haven't found out how to create these variables, to then be able to use it for the implementation in the column.

Sorry for the wall of text, hope you'll be able to help me, thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinbox/flutter_spinbox.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Dosierungsrechner';
  Color c = const Color.fromRGBO(17, 29, 78, 1.0);
  Color b = const Color.fromRGBO(223, 240, 250, 1.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title),
          centerTitle:true,
          backgroundColor: c,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget> [
                  Padding(
                    padding:const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height:60,
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                        color: b,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      ),

                        child: Align(
                          alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child:MyStatefulWidget(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child:Container(
                      height:40,
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                          color: b,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Anzahl der Mäuse:',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: SpinBox(
                              min: 0,
                              max: 100,
                              value: 0,
                              onChanged: (value) => print(value),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child:Container(
                      height:40,
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                          color: b,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Gewicht/Maus in g:',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: SpinBox(
                              min: 0,
                              max: 50,
                              value: 0,
                              onChanged: (value) => print(value),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text('Anzumischende Bestandteile',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height:200,
                decoration:BoxDecoration(
                    color: b,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Column(
                    children:[
                      Text('Midazolam 5mg/ml'),
                      Text('Medetomidin 5mg/ml'),
                      Text('Fentanyl 1mg/ml'),
                    ],
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Padding(
              padding:const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height:200,
                decoration:BoxDecoration(
                    color: b,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Testausgabe2'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<String> items = <String>['Protokoll auswählen', 'MMF', 'MM','MMB','AA','AAN'];
  String selectedItem = 'Protokoll auswählen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
      child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedItem,
          onChanged: (String string) => setState(() => selectedItem = string),
          selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
          return items.map<Widget>((String item) {
            return Text(item,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            );
          }).toList();
        },
        items: items.map((String item) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            child: Text('$item',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
            value: item,
          );
        }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for state management.

This is the point in the flutter journey where things can get quite complicated compared to how relatively easy and quick it is to build UI.

Here is a good tutorial on state management: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdUBV7AWL2U

I've updated your code with the simplest form of state management (streamBuilder).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinbox/flutter_spinbox.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

StreamController streamController = StreamController();

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  static const String _title = 'Dosierungsrechner';
  Color c = const Color.fromRGBO(17, 29, 78, 1.0);
  Color b = const Color.fromRGBO(223, 240, 250, 1.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: c,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: b,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      ),

                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: MyStatefulWidget(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: b,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Anzahl der Mäuse:',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: SpinBox(
                              min: 0,
                              max: 100,
                              value: 0,
                              onChanged: (value) => print(value),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: b,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Gewicht/Maus in g:',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: SpinBox(
                              min: 0,
                              max: 50,
                              value: 0,
                              onChanged: (value) => print(value),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Text('Anzumischende Bestandteile',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: b,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: streamController.stream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return updateBestandteile(snapshot.data);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: b,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Testausgabe2'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column updateBestandteile(String i) {
    switch (i) {
      case "MMF":
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('Midazolam 5mg/ml'),
              Text('Medetomidin 5mg/ml'),
              Text('Fentanyl 1mg/ml'),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          );
        }
        break;

      case "MM":
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('MM'),
              Text('MM'),
              Text('MM'),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          );
        }
        break;

      case "MMB":
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('MMB'),
              Text('MMB'),
              Text('MMB'),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          );
        }
        break;

      case "AA":
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('AA'),
              Text('AA'),
              Text('AA'),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          );
        }
        break;

      case "AAN":
        {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('AAN'),
              Text('AAN'),
              Text('AAN'),
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          );
        }
        break;

      default: { return Column(
        children: [
          Text('No choice made'),
          Text(''),
          Text(''),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      );}
      break;
    }

  }

}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<String> items = <String>['Protokoll auswählen', 'MMF', 'MM','MMB','AA','AAN'];
  String selectedItem = 'Protokoll auswählen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
      child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedItem,
          onChanged: (String string) => setState(() {
            streamController.sink.add(string);
            return selectedItem = string;
          }),
          selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return items.map<Widget>((String item) {
              return Text(item,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              );
            }).toList();
          },
          items: items.map((String item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              child: Text('$item',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              ),
              value: item,
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer and the code! Now I finally know what I need to look for! You're awesome :)